# How do I detect a click in an array of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a task calendar in excel.
The front page is a yearly calendar with all the months and days displayed.
There are individual tabs for each month to display the tasks. They will feed colors to the yearly calendar based on criteria Due soon, due today and over due.
What I want to do is:
If someone clicks on the month (comprised of an array of cells say(B2:I7 for January; j2:I7 for Feburary, etc.) it will go to the appropriate month tab. I know all the coding to make a sheet active, what I need is the "trigger" if any cell in the array is clicked (without a long loop list).

Comment: I would not do this with just one click. I don't imagine that would be very user friendly. Maybe consider a double click? Either way, these both exist as events. To check the range, just use `Intersect`

Comment: Events: [Selection Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange), [Double Click](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/beforedoubleclick-event.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your **worksheet's code module**, you can check via `Intersect`, if the selection is within the total calendar range, and then use the `Range.Area` of the multirange to define the month number:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RelevantArea As Range
    Dim Calendar As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set Calendar = Me.Range _
        ("B03:H10,J03:P10,R03:X10," & _
         "B12:H19,J12:P19,R12:X19," & _
         "B21:H28,J21:P28,R21:X28," & _
         "B30:H37,J30:P37,R30:X37")

    Set RelevantArea = Intersect(Target, Calendar)
    If Not RelevantArea Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To Calendar.Areas.Count
            If Not Intersect(Target, Calendar.Areas(i)) Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Month " & i & " selected."
                'Me.Parent.Sheets(1 + i).Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies. Once I got to work and tried to code it doesn't do what I need. The calendar page is in a 3 X 4 pattern with Jan Feb Mar in the first row, Apr, May, Jun in the next set of rows, etc.  I have my ranges established B3:h10 jan J3:p10 Feb R3:x10 Mar B12:h19 Apr, etc.

Comment: I edited it. If it works, please mark it as answer again.